# Safari on OSX renders linearGradient with fill-opacity unexpectedly

Tags: css, macos, svg, safari

I have an `SVG` block with a `<rect>` inside that uses a `fill` by referencing a `linearGradient` in another `SVG` block. The gradient's `<stop>` colours are defined in CSS along with the `<rect>`'s opacity of `0.8`.

In Safari on OSX the gradient looks poor, with the colours very washed out *(left)*. In Chrome on OSX the gradient looks correct *(right)*. All other browser/OS combinations work correctly.

[image: Safari (left) and Chrome (right)]

```css
svg #gradient > stop {
    stop-opacity: 1;
}

svg #gradient > stop.from {
    stop-color: #FBAD18;
}

svg #gradient > stop.to {
    stop-color: #FFD81C;
}

svg g rect {
  fill-opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop class="from" offset="0%"></stop>
      <stop class="to" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**Side note**

In my case, `dc.js` is the source of the `fill-opacity` CSS declaration on the `<rect>`. The other declarations are local to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `fill-opacity` from the `<rect>` and instead modifying the `stop-opacity` on the gradient solves the issue, but it is not clear why this only affects the Safari/OSX combination.

```css
svg #gradient > stop {
    stop-opacity: 0.8;
}

svg #gradient > stop.from {
    stop-color: #FBAD18;
}

svg #gradient > stop.to {
    stop-color: #FFD81C;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop class="from" offset="0%"></stop>
      <stop class="to" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```